# Define Element in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Hi i'm new to Haskell sorry if this question is to basic but i'm not understanding whats happening here.
I want to defiene a Element from Type Maybe Int

```
m :: Maybe Int

m = Just m | Nothing
```

but im getting an error:

```
 parse error on input `|'
   |
3 | m = Just m | Nothing 
   |            ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Why is this happening.

Comment: What does your `m = Just m | Nothing` means? You can not pass multiple values to the same variable.

Comment: I wanted to define m with another value than Nothing how should I do it then?

Comment: you can declare that variable with the value, like `m = Just 3` for example.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "Element". Do you want to create an alias for the type, or create your own type that contains or looks like a `Maybe Int`? Or do you actually want to create a concrete value of the type, and assign it to the `m` variable?

Comment: I thought about giving it any int value too but what sence makes the Maybe in this line? (m :: Maybe Int) My thought here was well if its not an Integer then give Nothing

Comment: I want to create my own type that contains or looks like a Maybe Int

Comment: @KevinZerull: but if there is already a `Maybe Int`, then why make your own type. I'm still quite confused *what* you aim to achieve here. Do you want to define a variable (with a value), a type, a function, something else?

Comment: The task is Define a Element m from the type Maybe Int with another value than Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step, you have to look at the definition of data type maybe:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

then, you can see two special functions there, called constructors, in your example, it can be used as:

```
m :: Maybe Int
m = Just 5
```

anothe example using the other constructor:

```
nothingHere :: Maybe a
nothingHere = Nothing
```

If you want to create your own data maybe it should be something like:

```
data MyMaybe a = None | Some a deriving Show

m :: MyMaybe Int
m = Some 5
```